# Entity Framework transaction isolation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have something very strange in a Blazor server application.

This Blazor application works with a SQL Server database and Entity Framework.

Here is a very basic service I've written:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    public String getInformationFromTable();
}

public class MyService
{
    private MyDbContext _db;

    public MyService(MyDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public String getInformationFromTable()
    {
         return _db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id=5).MyField;
    } 
}
```

I have declared this service as "transient" in `Startup`:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

`Startup.cs` also contains database configuration with this 2 lines:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cs);
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cs);
```

Now I have 2 web pages (Blazor server pages):

- The first one is calling getInformationFromTable through MyService:

  ```
  @page "/page1"
  @inject IMyService service

  ...

  public void onButtonClick()
  {
     Console.WriteLine(service.getInformationFromTable());
  }
  ```
- The second page is updating the information in the database:

  ```
  @page "/page2"
  @inject IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbc

  ....

  public void onButtonClick()
  {
     var db = dbc.CreateDbContext();
     db.MyTable...
     // This lines are changing MyField for Id 5
     db.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```

Now, an user opens page1 and page2 in 2 browser tabs:

In page1, the user hits the button and he can see the database information (MyField value for Id 5)

In page2, the user hits the button and he can update the database information

In page1, the user hits the same button... He can see the old value for MyField.

If user refreshes his browser tab and hits again the button, he can see the new value for Myfield.

My question is... why?

I suppose this is an isolation transaction problem:

- When Blazor loads page1, it instantiates `MyService` and a `DbContext`. I suppose Entity Framework starts a transaction and consider a "snapshot" of the database at this time.
- Then, I can do anything on page2, page1 won't take care of database changes due to isolated transaction.
- If I refresh page1, a new transaction is created.

Am I wrong ?

I do not understand why Entity Framework starts a transaction on page1, because I do not write anything in database in this page.

How can I resolve this ?

And do you think the problem comes from my service or from `dbcontext`?

Thanks

Comment: Consider modifying Entity Framework's log level to Verbal, to get a better picture

Answer (score 0):

Blazor isn't my thing (yet) but going out on a limb I would say the service isn't falling out of scope between "requests" while the user is on that page so the DbContext instance injected has a longer life than you expect.

DbContexts should live only as long as they are needed. Since you have defined a DbContextFactory, that should be the dependency for your service:

```
public class MyService
{
    private IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _dbc;

    public MyService(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbc)
    {
        _dbc = dbc;
    }

    public String getInformationFromTable()
    {
         using (var db = _dbc.CreateDbContext())
         {
             return db.MyTable.Single(i => i.Id=5).MyField;
         }
    } 
}
```

If the service doesn't fall out of scope between requests from the client then the issue you are seeing is that the DbContext is still alive so when you run the query again, even though you'd see a hit to the database, the DbContext would still return the instance it is already tracking, hence the stale data field.

A quick hack that can get around this is to query values with `AsNoTracking()` however, depending on how the DbContext instance is used throughout it's lifetime, if any one query loads that instance *without* `AsNoTracking()` you could still be returned that tracked instance in your query.

Note that if the DbContextFactory instance is instantiating a DbContext and returning it, it becomes the caller's responsibility to ensure it is disposed, so it should be wrapped in a `using` block.

Also, be wary of code like:

```
_db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id=5).MyField
```

While `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault` will generate the same SQL, First flavour methods would send back an entity if multiple records match your expression, where Single flavour methods enforce that you expect only one. This code would raise a NullReferenceException if a matching row wasn't found.

When you are truly interested in a First scenario you should always use an `OrderBy*` condition to ensure the results are repeatable.  When using `OrDefault` methods you should also always be prepared for the possibility that a value is not returned.

- If the code expects a value, and only 1 value, use `Single`
- If the code expects 1 value or no value: `SingleOrDefault`
- If the code expects many possible values, and wants the first one: `First`
- If the code expects many possible values or no value, and wants the first one or nothing: `FirstOrDefault`